# Adding class to ActionLink

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, controller, actionlink

I have action link with login button

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")
```

It works perfect redirecting user to `Account` controller `Login` action.
But When I'm trying to add class to style this button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

It does get style and looks good, but it loses controller info and redirects user to `Home/Login`, instead of `Account/Login`

Comment: What about this? `,null, new {@class = "..."}`

Comment: don't get it, can you write full line ?

Comment: I have provided an answer. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a null parameter before your style, because it refers to `routeValues`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

Have a look at it's documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__).

Comment: thanks, now I get it

Answer (score 1):

The fourth parameter in your [`ActionLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) helper refers to `routeValues` instead of `htmlAttributes`, which explains why you're redirected to another `Login` action.

You need to use `ActionLink` with 5 overloads like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `object routeValues` parameter after `ControllerName` and no such overload as `ActionLink(link text, action name, controller name, htmlAttributes)`, so try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

Use :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", null,new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

In 5 overloaded method you are setting **htmlAttributes** to the **routeValues**.
That is why it doesn't behaves as you aspected.